# NodeMCU Lua integer max value is 2^31

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 3.0.1-dev(fce080e)
Trying to use node.dsleepMax() and it is returning a really smaller number (147324921). Then I tried to manually set the sleep time in node.dsleep to the 32-bit max value (4294967295) and it only remained sleeping for around 30 min or so.

Tried the following:

```
    sleeptime = 4294967295
    > 
    =print(sleeptime)

2147483647
```

which is 2^31 -1.

Also did a loop adding to a variable, and it becomes negatve when it reaches 2^31.

Questions:

1. Why is the variable wrapping at 2^31?
2. Isn't node.dsleep supposed to accept a 64-bit value with SDK 2.1 and above?

Regards,

Cesar

Comment: It is very likely that you are using firmware int version (32bit) instead of of float (32bit with 23bit precision). This limitation is in lua and not in SDK.

Comment: Darius, I thought about it, but wanted to verify before building another firmware. I am using the integer firmware. So, it is a signed integer, therefore 31 bit plus sign info, is that correct?

Comment: Max positive signed int is exactly 2^31-1. In lua source code file `node.c` function `node_deepsleep` internally uses uint64 with `system_deep_sleep`. But if you use float firmware you loses precision in calculating sleep time i.e. float number 2^23 == 2^23+1

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already got some feedback regarding int vs. float. As for `dsleep` [the documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/node/#nodedsleep) doesn't explicitly state that it accepts 64bit values but that's indeed what's happening as per https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/2358 (since April 2018).

Comment: Thank you Marcel! I saw the info on the 64-bit from the link provided in the documentation that points to your article on Thingpulse. I just didn't thing that I would need the float firmware for that, since it is an integer number.
I have just flashed a float firmware and it works fine :-)

Comment: Sorry about the missing hint. We at NodeMCU also accept PRs that improve the documentation ;-)